# Why was this edit allowed?

Tags: discussion, edits

This [edit by Shamoon](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/136872/revisions) is **wrong**. OP answered his own question, correctly, and the edit causes the answer to no longer answer OP's question.

Isn't it considered bad practice to edit code? *Especially* if it's in an answer written and accepted by OP?

This answer now gives the format that many are looking for (which another answer already did), but does *not* answer the OP's question. It's quite confusing.

And since the edit is recent considering the age of the post, I imagine that most of the upvotes happened before the edit. I tried to rollback the edit and submit a clarification, but it was rejected.

Comment: Part of the problem seems to be all of the misleading comments on the confusing answer to the confusing question.

Comment: @sixlettervariables which is why I added a clarification to my edit, but it was rejected. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2187025

Comment: @toxalot -- to be honest, that edit was pretty bad, and I see why users would have rejected it.  The commentary should have been in the Edit Summary, not the answer itself.

Comment: But the commentary clarifies all the comments. I think it clears up all the misunderstandings.

Comment: It's worth noting that while the user doesn't have 2k rep now, and as such requires their edits to be reviewed, he did at the time of that edit until he [lost over 1000 rep due to serial voting reversals](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vaD8Y.png).  That leads me to believe he may have done other malicious activities around that time; probably worth a mod looking into it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was obviously an invalid edit, those do happen, and we have to be diligent to fix them and move on.

It's not bad practice per-se to update code posted by the OP, if something as simple as an API typo (e.g. `toStirng()` to `toString()`) is there, but that was not what this was. In any situation, if an edit is made to an answer (where the editor isn't the post owner), where it fundamentally changes the code, then yes, it is invalid.

I have rolled back the edit, keep your eyes open, though.

Comment: Is it possible to approve my suggested edit? It adds the clarification that I think is needed. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2187025

Comment: @Toxalot No. That's invalid as well. Read the reject reasons. The post  is indeed confusing, but without removing the comments below (via flagging) it will remain confusing no matter what you do.

Comment: I understand the reject reasons. But, in this case, doesn't it clarify, and therefore improve, the answer? Posting another comment would add to the confusion. Posting another answer would be redundant.

Comment: @toxalot The confusing thing here is the 100+ comment below it. I have flagged it as 'obsolete', and hopefully it gets removed. I think that, along with Matt's edit, should make the post better moving forward.

Comment: I flagged the answer asking that all of the comments be deleted as they are terribly misleading.

Comment: @toxalot That edit is essentially putting a meta discussion into the post.  It doesn't really belong anywhere other than the revision comment.  Remember that posts should make sense when being read by someone for the first time, and not look like a discussion all manged together through various edits.

Comment: @toxalot your suggested edit adds something to the answer which was not originally part of it, and which is not required to understand it. So no, it does not clarify or improve the answer.  If you want that content to appear in the answer list it should be posted as a separate answer, but as you pointed out you would be answering something other than what was asked.

Comment: Oh and don't be shy about doling out downvotes for everybody who didn't understand the question and had a wrong answer. Far too many wrong answers. Granted the question itself deserves a downvote too.

Comment: @sixlettervariables DOWNVOTERS: ATTACK!!!

Comment: *If* the comments get deleted, I see how Matt's edit does the best job at improving the answer.

Comment: What about the comments on that answer? I flagged 3 of them (`Erik Your MySQL quotation...`, `This will fail if the...`, `Im not sure the edit made recently...`) as obsolete, but they are still there. The second one is just confusing, but the other two are definitely obsolete. The first references a comment that no longer exists and the third refers to an edit that has since been rolled back.

Comment: @toxalot there's nothing you can do but wait at this point, unfortunately.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There's no way to tell if *comment* flags have been reviewed (that I see). But it's been my experience that my suggestions/flags get reviewed almost instantaneously, so I assumed that my flags had been rejected.

Comment: @toxalot: my answer flag was marked "helpful" but no action was taken. I asked specifically that the comments be torched and referenced this meta question.